# Django pre_delete model method executing unexpectedly

Tags: django, django-models

Models:

I have three models:

Packet, Item and Transaction.

Packet model:

```
class Packet(models.Model):
    """
    Packet model
    """
    #Some Fields
```

Item Model:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    """
    Item model class
    """
    packet = models.ForeignKey(Packet,
                               verbose_name='related packet',
                               )
    #Some Fields

@receiver(pre_delete)
def copy_item_details(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """
    :param sender:
    :param instance:
    :param kwargs:
    :return:
    """
    #Some code
```

Transaction model:

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    """
    Transaction Model
    """
    packet = models.ForeignKey(Packet,
                               verbose_name='related packet',
                               )
    #Some Fields
```

My problem is if i try to delete instance of Transaction class. The method(copy_item_details) defined in Item model class is executing. Why is it so???? `copy_item_details` should only execute when instance of Item model class is deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify sender of signal in `@receiver` definition:

```
@receiver(pre_delete, sender=Item)
def copy_item_details(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    """
    :param sender:
    :param instance:
    :param kwargs:
    :return:
    """
    #Some code
```

NOTE:
Signals should be placed in signals.py not in model.
According to Django docs:

> "Strictly speaking, signal handling and registration code can live
>   anywhere you like, although it’s recommended to avoid the
>   application’s root module and its models module to minimize
>   side-effects of importing code.
>
> In practice, signal handlers are usually defined in a signals
>   submodule of the application they relate to."

Here is a [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/signals/) for you.

Comment: As i want to execute this method for Item model. And can you tell me why this is happening....???